# views contextual filter by current year missing granularity

Tags: 8, views

In a view I need a contextual filter: all nodes with creation date in the current year.

In D7 i was able to provide the current date as default value and set a granularity for the date, e.g. the year.

In D8 I don't have any options to granular configure the filter.

Is there any other solution to set this contextual filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use specific granularity field that you wish to add.
like there are multiple option given in contextual filter which are as under.

- Created year >> Content Date in the form of YYYY.

in that field you can specify in "Provide default value"  as "current date".

Comment: Oh, 'Created year' did it. I used the wrong field. Thank you!